# how can i create a grid with java using toStrings

Tags: java

Hi Im new to java and I would like to create a grid using java

I want my output to look like this

```
1 2 
3 4
```

How can I do it with just the toStrings method? I am thinking of using a constructor where if I put  (int 2) then it will give me this grid, and if it is  (int 3) then it will look like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Give it a shot. A simple loop is all that is needed.

Comment: Pro tip: Use `System.out.print(int)` to print values side by side and use `.println()` to print a new line.

Comment: @Eritrean how can I loop it? I am thinking of doing a loop where i pass in start and end number but I have no idea where to start

Comment: @asd-qwert you need nested loops. The outer loop iterates through the rows and the inner loop iterates through the values of each row.

Comment: I have the answer, but I would like you to try and post the code you used to try it.

Comment: @asd-qwert also, `toString()` is not the appropriate method to use in this case. This method is used to provide a string representation of the **entire class** and not of just a single attribute of a class.

Comment: @hfontanez it's possible this grid is the value of the entire class.

Comment: @DavidConrad while that is true, that probably will be a misuse of a class. Although, I see what you are implying which is to make a wrapper class for this specific data structure.

Comment: @hfontanez Well, there are very few details in the question, but if the class is `Grid` and it just represents a grid, then it seems reasonable that the `toString()` would return the grid, although `toString()` methods that return strings with embedded line separators are a bit... vexatious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested for loops. Your method need to take 3 parameters for the row count and column count and also a start number (if say you want to start from 10 instead of 1)

```
private static String generateGrid(int rows, int cols, int start){
        StringBuilder gridBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int nextNumber = start;
        for(int row = 0 ; row < rows; row++){
           for(int col = 0 ; col < cols; col++){
                gridBuilder.append(nextNumber);
                gridBuilder.append(" ");
                nextNumber++;
           }
           gridBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        return gridBuilder.toString();
    }
```

The method returns a String. You are free to print the result or use it for other purposes

Comment: This might work, but why so complicated?

Comment: You might want to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `"\n"` to be platform-independent.

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer was already provided, I will post mine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    printGrid(matrix);
}

public static void printGrid(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        for (int value : row) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If you are really concerned about the extra space next to the value, add a string buffer and trim it out before displaying:

```
public static void printGrid(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (int value : row) {
            buffer.append(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString().trim());
    }
}
```

By the way, the output of this program is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Instead of trimming, you could convert them to strings and join them like this: `Arrays.stream(row).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))`

Comment: @DavidConrad yeah.... for this OP that might be a little bit above his technical knowledge.

Comment: We are not providing answers just for the OP, though, but for the question. Although this question is rather narrow and it may not be helpful to too many others.

Comment: @DavidConrad "_this question is rather narrow and it may not be helpful to too many others_" - this was precisely my thought when I posted my answer. I was just trying to help this person. I want to believe that most developers out there would know how to iterate through a 2D array using conventional loops. This is done at nauseam in text books.